# Constructor Function vs Object.create - What is the difference and application?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

Coming for Java, I am trying to understand Javascript OOP correctly. I've read about it but haven't intuitively understood the difference and application of the two methods of object creation and inheritance.

> Object.create

**As I understand: Object.create() sets the a given object's prototype to that object passed into .create()?**

So for example.

```
const Cat = {
    init: function(sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
            return this
    },
    makeSound: function() {
        console.log(this.sound);
    }
}
var mark = Object.create(Cat);
mark.init('meoow!');
mark.makeSound();

console.log(mark);
```

***Here mark's prototype object is being referenced to Cat object? Right?***
If that is true

**Question 1:** Why doesn't JS just set the parent class's object to the subclass (instead of its prototype)?

**Question 2:** What exactly is the use of having a prototype object linked with every object? Wouldn't inheritance be more comfortable if we just had one object referencing another?

**Question 3:** I've read it's not good practice to set prototype fields of an object? We should only work with actual object fields and methods, is it true and why? i.e.  `Cat.prototype.age = 10;`

> new Object()

In the following code...

```
function cat() {
 this.sound = 'wooof!';
}
    var filly = new cat();
    console.log(filly.sound);
    console.log(filly);
```

**Question 4:** filly's actual object inherits the property of cat (or the filly's prototype object)?

*It seems evident I don't understand how, when and why prototype objects are used in JavaScript perhaps?*

Please help!

Comment: A lot of these questions are pretty broad and seem to be asking why design decisions were made, which is a bit off topic here. But to question 4: the `filly` object is a brand new object created by `new cat()` -- it's the 'this' in the function. Its prototype points to an object (also confusingly called `prototype`) that is a property of the `cat` function. I'm sure it's unnatural coming from a language like Java, but it helps to forget about OO terms like classes and inheritance and just focus on objects referencing each other. Then it's still peculiar in spots, but pretty simple.